# c++ char** convert c#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have a dll file and a structure is defined as like below,

```
typedef struct test{
    DWORD NOD;          // Number of the devices ready to work
    char **a;       // Array of 16 byte ASCII strings
    char **b;       // Array of 4 byte ASCII strings
} test;
```

And I want to declare this structure at c# so I know I must use Marshal but how should I do?

my dll import function

```
[DllImport("USMCDLL.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern UInt32 USMC_Init(ref USMC_Devices str);
```

and I use it like

```
Test DVS = new Test();

public void Init_()
{
    fonk(ref DVS);
}
```

Comment: More explanation about what you want to do with the structure is welcome.

Comment: Please add cases how you going to use it in managed code

Comment: I think its a bad idea. you should create a cli wrapper.

Comment: Please also provide the signature of the unmanaged function.